# Rendering Json response in grails view

Tags: json, grails, dictionary

I am querying twitter api to get the tweets with a `hashtag` in `grails 2.1.1`.

**My Controller is**

```
import grails.converters.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*; // package containing JSONObject, JSONArray,...
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

    class NepTweetController {
        def index() {
              //def restEndpointUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23nepal";
              def restEndpointUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23nepal";
              def http = new HTTPBuilder(restEndpointUrl);

              // perform a GET request, expecting JSON response data
              http.request( GET, JSON ) {
                    //uri.path = '/search.json'
                    //uri.query = [ q: '%23nepal' ]
                                response.success = { resp, json ->
                                             // def tweetsResult = json.results;
                                             // List parsedList = JSON.parse(json) as List;
                                             // JSONObject tweetJson = JSON.parse(json);
                                             //def tweetJson = JSON.parse(json);
                                              def tweets = new JSON(json) as Map;

                                              render(view: "index", model: [message: "Request sent" , tweets: tweets]);
                                 }
              }//end of request
        }//end of method
    }
```

I successfully get the [json response](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#nepal) as follows :

```
  {
      "completed_in": 0.017,
      "max_id": 271907240007581696,
      "max_id_str": "271907240007581696",
      "next_page": "?page=2&max_id=271907240007581696&q=%23nepal%2F",
      "page": 1,
      "query": "%23nepal%2F",
      "refresh_url": "?since_id=271907240007581696&q=%23nepal%2F",
      "results": [
        {
          "created_at": "Fri, 23 Nov 2012 09:25:12 +0000",
          "from_user": "iBshnu",
          "from_user_id": 25051623,
          "from_user_id_str": "25051623",
          "from_user_name": "Bishnu Bhattarai",
          "geo": null,
          "id": 271907240007581696,
          "id_str": "271907240007581696",
          "iso_language_code": "ne",
          "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent"
          },
          "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2622309791\/42z33jnw1kak9ttyqkrf_normal.jpeg",
          "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2622309791\/42z33jnw1kak9ttyqkrf_normal.jpeg",
          "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/twitter.com\/&quot;&gt;web&lt;\/a&gt;",
          "text": "RT @dipakbhattarai: \u0930\u093e\u0937\u094d\u091f\u094d\u0930\u092a\u0924\u093f \u0921\u093e. \u0930\u093e\u092e\u092c\u0930\u0923 \u092f\u093e\u0926\u0935\u0926\u094d\u0935\u093e\u0930\u093e \u092e\u0919\u094d\u0938\u093f\u0930 \u0967\u096a \u092d\u093f\u0924\u094d\u0930 \u0926\u0932\u0939\u0930\u0941\u0932\u093e\u0908 \u0930\u093e\u0937\u094d\u091f\u094d\u0930\u093f\u092f \u0938\u0939\u092e\u0924\u093f\u0915\u094b \u0938\u0930\u0915\u093e\u0930 \u092c\u0928\u093e\u0909\u0928 \u0906\u0935\u094d\u0939\u093e\u0928\u0964 #Nepal",
          "to_user": null,
          "to_user_id": 0,
          "to_user_id_str": "0",
          "to_user_name": null
        },
        {
          "created_at": "Fri, 23 Nov 2012 09:24:58 +0000",
          "from_user": "Phanindra07",
          "from_user_id": 63104333,
          "from_user_id_str": "63104333",
          "from_user_name": "Phanindra Dahal",
          "geo": null,
          "id": 271907179404095488,
          "id_str": "271907179404095488",
          "iso_language_code": "en",
          "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent"
          },
          "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2417859753\/febstuo4p4zltimnpky0_normal.jpeg",
          "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2417859753\/febstuo4p4zltimnpky0_normal.jpeg",
          "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/twitter.com\/&quot;&gt;web&lt;\/a&gt;",
          "text": "RT @DeepakAdk: Chef's assault on #Nepal #Maoist reflects grassroots anger, excellent piece by my #AFP colleague @FrankieTaggart http:\/\/t.co\/M47qJeoD",
          "to_user": null,
          "to_user_id": 0,
          "to_user_id_str": "0",
          "to_user_name": null
        }
[....more....]
```

My `/views/nepTweet/index.gsp` is

```
<meta name='layout' content='main'/>
<b>${message}</b>

<p>Tweets</p>
<g:each in="${tweets}" var="tweet">
     <p>${tweet.text}</p>
</g:each>
```

But, I get error parsing json to grails Map.

**Error I get is :**

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/WhoTweetsNepal/nepTweet
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: grails.converters.JSON.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: every()
```

I went through [How do I access A JSON Object(String) from GSP page?](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-do-I-access-A-JSON-Object-String-from-GSP-page-td3533057.html), but couldn't get help.

Helpppp!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With to the point suggestions from [Ian Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530324/432903), I got the solution with my final Controller to be(realising there is no need to parse it) :

```
import grails.converters.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.*; // package containing JSONObject, JSONArray,...
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*


    class NepTweetController {
        def index() {
              def restEndpointUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23nepal";
              def http = new HTTPBuilder(restEndpointUrl);

              // perform a GET request, expecting JSON response data
              http.request( GET, ContentType.JSON ) {
                    //uri.path = '/search.json'
                    //uri.query = [ q: '%23nepal' ]
                                response.success = { resp, json ->
                                             def tweetsResult = json.results;

                                              render(view: "index", model: [message: "Request sent" , tweets: tweetsResult]);
                                 }
              }//end of request
        }//end of method
    }
```

Comment: Hi Prayag, how'd you resolve the groovx.net.http dependencies?  I tried a couple solutions I found on the web but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Have a look at [NepTweetsController.groovy](https://github.com/iPrayag/WhoTweetsNepal/blob/NepalTweets/grails-app/controllers/whotweetsnepal/NepTweetController.groovy) and [BuildConfig.groovy](https://github.com/iPrayag/WhoTweetsNepal/blob/NepalTweets/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy) available at github. Hope it helps you.   Dependency should be     `compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0') {
                     excludes "commons-logging", "xml-apis", "groovy"
        }`

Answer (score 4):

You definitely want

```
def tweetJson = JSON.parse(json);
```

(which will return a `JSONObject`, which is a `Map`) instead of

```
def tweetJson = new JSON(json) as Map;
```

but it looks like you have a bit of a name clash in your code - presumably the JSON in

```
http.request( GET, JSON )
```

is intended to be the HTTPBuilder content type rather than `grails.converters.JSON`.  If you can clear up this name clash (i.e. remove the `import static` and say `ContentType.JSON`) then things may run more smoothly.